# What if I have to separate to columns when I have multiple spaces separating column values?

Tags: python, split

I have the following info from a txt file that I'm trying to save to a df:

```
Description:           Master Index of EDGAR Dissemination Feed by Company Name
Last Data Received:    February  2, 2023
Comments:              webmaster@sec.gov
Anonymous FTP:         ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/
 
 
 
 
Company Name                                                  Form Type   CIK         Date Filed  File Name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 800 FLOWERS COM INC                                         8-K         1084869     2023-02-02  edgar/data/1084869/0001157523-23-000149.txt         
1.21 Gigawatts AI Fund QP, LP - A3                            D           1961799     2023-01-17  edgar/data/1961799/0001961800-23-000002.txt         
1.21 Gigawatts AI Fund, LP - A3                               D           1961800     2023-01-17  edgar/data/1961800/0001961800-23-000002.txt
```

I know how to remove the headers/unnecessary rows, and then I store it to a df. But then when trying to split columns in the df, it does not work because there MULTIPLE spaces between each variable's value. Any suggestions.

I've tried: `split_df = df1[0].str.split(r'\s+', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

text = '''\
Description:           Master Index of EDGAR Dissemination Feed by Company Name
Last Data Received:    February  2, 2023
Comments:              webmaster@sec.gov
Anonymous FTP:         ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/

Company Name                                                  Form Type   CIK         Date Filed  File Name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 800 FLOWERS COM INC                                         8-K         1084869     2023-02-02  edgar/data/1084869/0001157523-23-000149.txt
1.21 Gigawatts AI Fund QP, LP - A3                            D           1961799     2023-01-17  edgar/data/1961799/0001961800-23-000002.txt
1.21 Gigawatts AI Fund, LP - A3                               D           1961800     2023-01-17  edgar/data/1961800/0001961800-23-000002.txt
'''

rows = re.findall(r'(?m)^(.*?)\s{2,}(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)', text.split('----')[-1])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Company Name', 'Form Type', 'CIK', 'Date Filed', 'File Name'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         Company Name Form Type      CIK  Date Filed                                    File Name
0               1 800 FLOWERS COM INC       8-K  1084869  2023-02-02  edgar/data/1084869/0001157523-23-000149.txt
1  1.21 Gigawatts AI Fund QP, LP - A3         D  1961799  2023-01-17  edgar/data/1961799/0001961800-23-000002.txt
2     1.21 Gigawatts AI Fund, LP - A3         D  1961800  2023-01-17  edgar/data/1961800/0001961800-23-000002.txt
```